# Registering an application on twitter

Tags: android

I am trying to post on twitter having an register application. But every-time whenever i am editing my application to make it read&write  it always shows read only and whenever i am trying to edit it and save it, again it shows "**This is an application to check twitter authorization.
created by Piyush – read-only access by default**  ".For that reason i am not able to post my comments on twitter.

My application gives an

```
 //401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.

{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST"}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I thought that recently Twitter announced that they were no longer allowing third parties to use their API. Wonder if this has anything to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer don't use the similar page for the setting, use twitter developer url: https://dev.twitter.com go for this link and make your settings again and it works :).